# Qual é a melhor maneira de usar threading nesse exemplo?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Esse é o desafio:

> Crie uma função que mostre um item de uma lista a cada segundo. Utilizando threads, faça o programa mostrar todos itens o mais rápido possível

Meu codigo:

```
import threading
import time

threads = int(input('Quantas threads você deseja? '))
lista = list(range(0, 50000))


if threads > len(lista):
    threads = len(lista)

passo = len(lista) // threads
n = 0
n2 = passo

def thread(n, n2):
    for i in lista[n:n2]:
        print(i)
        time.sleep(1)


for i in range(threads - 1):
    threading.Thread(target=thread, args=(n, n2)).start()
    n = n2
    n2 += passo
threading.Thread(target=thread, args=(n, len(lista))).start()
```

Ele funciona, porém os prints não são em ordem, existe alguma maneira de deixa-los em ordem com a mesma eficiencia ou até mais?

Também percebi que o trabalho de cada thread é diferente (a ultima thread normalmente tem mais itens), então algumas terminam muito rápido, e outras muito devagar. Existe alguma maneira de deixar um numero de threads "fixo" até que o programa liste todos itens?

Answer (score 1):

Uma solução é passar para cada Thread uma parte contínua da lista, como `[..., n, n+1, n+2, ...]` e fazer cada Thread montar um texto para ser impresso. Depois cada Thread imprime seu próprio texto.

```
num_threads = int(input('Quantas threads você deseja? '))
lista = list(range(0, 20000))

lock = threading.Lock()

# Cada Thread imprime uma parte contínua da lista
def imprime_lista(*lista):
    texto = '\n'.join(map(str, lista))
    with lock:
        print(texto)

total_valores = len(lista)
lista_threads = []

# Passa uma parte da lista para a cada Thread
for i in range(num_threads):
    lim_inf = int((i)*(total_valores/num_threads)) # Limite inferior para divisão da lista
    lim_sup = int((i+1)*(total_valores/num_threads)) # Limite superior para divisão da lista
    lista_threads.append(threading.Thread(target=imprime_lista, args=(lista[lim_inf:lim_sup])))

for t in lista_threads:
    t.start()
```

Com o `Lock()` é possível bloquear uma Thread de acessar parte do código. Como todas as Threads executam a mesma função, todas formam o texto a ser impresso paralelamente, mas são bloqueadas antes de imprimir o texto.

Com o comando `with lock:`, eu garanto que cada Thread vai imprimir seu texto e depois liberar para que outra Thread faça o mesmo. Assim as impressões não se sobressaem.

Nos testes que eu fiz, talvez por todas executarem a mesma função, a ordem em que as Threads imprimiram seus respectivos textos (ou seja, acessavam a parte bloqueada) seguiu a ordem em que foram inicializadas pelo `t.start()`.

Comment: poderia me explicar o uso de threading.lock()?

Comment: Editei adicionando uma breve explicação com o que sei. Desculpe se não é o suficiente para seu problema, mas meu conhecimento de `Threads` com `Lock` não vai muito além disso.

Comment: gostei desse método de adicionar as threads em uma lista, com certeza vou usar

Comment: Como o `total_valores` e o `num_threads` são fixos, colocaria o cálculo deles `total_valores/num_threads` fora do looping pra evitar refazer-lo.